# Pass data from template to related component

Tags: html, css, angular

How to pass data from template to component (not child or parent component) without having anything to fire an event (like a button or a form). In the example below, how to pass the item in items to the component?

items.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"></div>
```

items.component.ts

```
onInit(item) {
console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: check `@Input, @Output, EventEmitter` topics.

Comment: You should run through a basic tutorial (see e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply call a previously created function in the .ts of the related component, for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{displayName(item)}}}
</div>
```

And in your .ts

```
public items = [ { id: 1, name: 'nesticle' }, { id: 2, name: 'emulator' } ]
    
displayName(item: any): void {
   console.log(item);
   return item.name;
}
```